# Creating Bootstrap Modal Dialog using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am trying to create a Bootstrap Modal dialog using JavaScript. The reason I am doing it with JavaScript is because I want to be able to render it later using custom elements (i.e. title, error message). I am fairly new to JavaScript so I do not understand why the code is not executed when I call the function ***errorMessage()***. Can anyone please help out by letting me know what the mistake is and how I can correct it? Is there a more efficient way of doing it?  Thank you very much.

By the way I did link the **modal.js** file to the HTML doc and I am aware of **bootboxjs**, but I don't want to use it for now.

```
// Creation of the alert message box.
function errorMessage() {
    var Modal = document.createElement('div');
    Modal.id = 'myModal';
    Modal.className = 'modal fade show';
    // To set up the attributes.
    Modal.setAttribute("data-backdrop", "static");
    Modal.setAttribute("data-keyboard", false);
    document.body.appendChild(Modal);

        var dialog = document.createElement('div');
        dialog.className = 'modal-dialog';
        Modal.appendChild(dialog);

            var content = document.createElement('div');
            content.className = 'modal-content';
            dialog.appendChild(content);

                var header = document.createElement('div');
                header.className = 'modal-header';
                content.appendChild(header);

                    var title = document.createElement('h4');
                    title.className = 'modal-title';
                    title.createTextNode = 'Data Error';
                    header.appendChild(header);

                var body = document.createElement('div');
                body.className = 'modal-body';
                dialog.appendChild(body);

                    var message = document.createElement('p');
                    message.createTextNode("Oh... snap. We can't find any items in your list. Please make sure your entry is structured as following:");
                    body.appendChild(message);

                    var representation = document.createElement('div');
                    representation.className = 'well';
                    body.appendChild(representation);

                        var representationTxt = document.createElement('p');
                        representationTxt.style.fontStyle = 'italic';
                        representationTxt.createTextNode('> Subheader , tag1 , tag2, tag3');
                        representation.appendChild(representationTxt);

                var footer = document.createElement('div');
                footer.className = 'modal-footer';
                dialog.appendChild(footer);

                    var closeBtn = document.createElement('button');
                    closeBtn.setAttribute("data-dismiss", "modal");
                    closeBtn.setAttribute("type", "button");
                    closeBtn.className = 'btn btn-primary btn-inverse';
                    closeBtn.value = 'I got it. Thanks.';
                    footer.appendChild(closeBtn);

    // Show modal dialog box
    $("#myModal").modal('show');

}
```

Comment: Are you actually using jQuery? If so, you could just hard code these elements (instead of making them with JavaScript) with both the class that you want and the `hidden` class. Then, when an event happens, remove the `hidden` class.

Answer (score 0):

It is failing on this line: `header.appendChild(header);` because it cannot append header to itself.  Did you mean this?

```
var title = document.createElement('h4');
title.className = 'modal-title';
title.createTextNode = 'Data Error';
header.appendChild(title);
```

A debugging tool is invaluable in javascript development (Firebug add-on for Firefox or the built-in tools in Chrome, for example).  You would have seen this error right away :)